# Click link twice to activate the state with ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Initially the **schoolyears** state is active.

When I click on the button to activate the **schoolyears.create** state I have to do this action TWICE. Only then the create schoolyear view is rendered.

What do I wrong?

**INDEX.HTML**

```
// navbar removed for brevity

<div ui-view="content" class="container body-content">
        CONTENT
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('TGB', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])

  .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    }
  ])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      //localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('TGB');
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("schoolyears");
      $stateProvider
        .state('schoolyears', {
            url: '/schoolyears',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: "/js/schoolyears/schoolyears.html",
                    controller: 'SchoolyearsController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('schoolyears.selected', {
            url: '/:id'
        }) 
        .state('schoolyears.create', {
            url: '/create',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: '/js/schoolyears/createSchoolyear.html',
                    controller: 'CreateSchoolyearController'
                }
            }
        })
  });
```

**SchoolyearsController.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('TGB')
      .controller('SchoolyearsController', SchoolyearsController);

    function SchoolyearsController($scope, $state) {

        $scope.schoolyears = []; 
    }
})();
```

**CreateSchoolyearController.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('TGB')
      .controller('CreateSchoolyearController', CreateSchoolyearController);

     function CreateSchoolyearController($scope, $state) {



    }
})();
```

Comment: When I twist the order of the states schoolyears.select with schoolyears.create THEN it WORKS! But why? AFAIR the order is not important... the dot notation in the state determines the hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that just set up a state as below

```
    .state('schoolyears.create', {
        url: '/create',
        views: {
            'content@schoolyears': {
                templateUrl: '/js/schoolyears/createSchoolyear.html',
                controller: 'CreateSchoolyearController'
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: that did not work at all. Every time I clicked the create button then the schoolyears view with the datetime.now fields got refreshed and I saw a new datetime.